# How do you hyperlink a transformed SVG

Tags: html, svg, hyperlink

I have an SVG with four transformed quarter circles. I want to make each of these quarter circles clickable, and able to take the user to a different link. How do I accomplish this?

Code:

```
      <svg width="400" height="400">
        <path id="quartertl" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
          style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
        <path id="quartertr" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
        style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
        <path id="quarterbr" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
        style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
        <path id="quarterbl" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
        style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>

        <use transform="translate(195,195) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
        <use transform="translate(200,195) rotate(90) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
        <use transform="translate(200,200) rotate(180) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
        <use transform="translate(195,200) rotate(270) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Please read about [the <a> SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) that creates a hyperlink to other web pages,

Comment: I tried wrapping one of the paths in an <a> tag but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Make your code snippet run, so we play with it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to use the SVG `<a>` element.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <path id="quartertl" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
    style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
  <path id="quartertr" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
    style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
  <path id="quarterbr" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
    style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>
  <path id="quarterbl" d="M0,0 L-200,0  A200,200 0 0,1    0,-200 z" 
    style="fill:green;fill-opacity: 1;stroke:black;stroke-width: 1"/>

  <a xlink:href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
    <use transform="translate(195,195) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
  </a>
  <use transform="translate(200,195) rotate(90) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
  <use transform="translate(200,200) rotate(180) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
  <use transform="translate(195,200) rotate(270) scale(0.7,0.7)" xlink:href="#quartertl"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see where I went wrong, I tried to wrap <path> instead of <use> in the <a>